# Is there a way to know what task if being performed by the active threads in the ThreadPool?

Tags: .net, multithreading, service, threadpool

**Background...**
I have a Windows Service with many components in it that all run on schedules.  Each component processes files but performs specific tasks to the files based on the current status they are at in our system.  These components currently create Threads (System.Threading.Thread) for each file being processed, within each component in the service.

Component 1 might be pulling files down from an FTP site.
Component 2 might be unzipping a file to the hard drive.
Component 3 might be decrypting files on the hard drive.
Component 4 might be copying or moving files from one place to another.

Currently, each component kicks off its component specific task in a new Thread, per file being processed.  This has worked out well for us, but as the system and company grows, it's becoming more and more difficult to manage.  I am looking into the ThreadPool (System.Threading.ThreadPool) for both easier thread management and better resource management overall.

Here's a simplified current design...

```
'send a message that the component task has begun
Comms.ComponentStatus(ComponentID, Running)

For Each f As File
  Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf processFile)
  t.Start(f)

  lst.Add(t)
Next

'some list checking to see if all threads in list are done

Do Until lst has no active threads

Loop

'all threads complete so the component task is complete
Comms.ComponentStatus(ComponentID, Complete)
```

**My dilemma...**
I created a dashboard that receives real-time messages (.Net Remoting) about each component and task being performed.  Trace info, exception info and most importantly the Start and End of a component's task overall.  In my current design, I message that a task has begun, create threads for each file to be processed and keep track of the threads created.  I look at all threads created for the task and when they are all complete, I message that the task has completed.  This works very well for us.  With a ThreadPool design, all of my components will be pulling threads from a process-wide thread pool, allowing the system to manage them, but not allowing me to know which threads are being used for which tasks within each component, therefore not allowing me to know when a component's task is complete.

A quick look into .Net's ThreadPool does not show me that I can determine which active threads in the pool are performing which tasks.  Does anyone have a solution or suggestion?  Thanks in advance.

```
'this only returns a bool telling me the requested task will be performed
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

'this only returns to me a number of threads available for queue
ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads()
```

Comment: After pondering my options for 24 hours, I came up with a design to help manage and keep track of what I put into the ThreadPool and when it finishes.  I will post about the design/solution after some coding & testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I decided to do is create a Class that holds onto information about the task being performed including the Component's ID, the Task's ID, and a Thread Count.  Whenever the task runs, it creates an instance of this object at the component level (Class level).  This allows me to isolate counts of threads at the component level.  When it queues threads in the ThreadPool, it increments the thread counter in the object.  When all threads have been queued it sits and waits for the thread counter to return to 0, therefore marking the task as complete.  The thread counter gets decremented each time the delegate for the thread has finished processing (the thread is complete).  I put a catchall timespan to get out of the thread count loop in case something unforeseen happens.  A quick code and test showed me conceptually it does work.  I will continue to code and test and if any findings occur that result in changes, I will post them here.

Here's my initial outline of the thread tracking object.

```
Public Class TaskTracker : Implements IDisposable

    Public ReadOnly Property ComponentID As Integer = 0
    Public ReadOnly Property TaskUID As Guid = Guid.Empty
    Public ReadOnly Property ThreadCount As Integer = 0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create a new instance of the TaskTracker object.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="ComponentID">The ID of the Component this object belongs to.</param>
    ''' <param name="TaskUID">The UID of the Task in question.</param>
    Public Sub New(ComponentID As Integer, TaskUID As Guid)

        Try
            _ComponentID = ComponentID
            _TaskUID = TaskUID
            _ThreadCount = 0
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log.Save(Log.Types.Error, ComponentID, TaskUID, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Increment the internal thread count property by the amount in the value provided.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Value">The amount to increment the thread count by.</param>
    Public Sub IncrementThreadCount(Optional Value As Integer = 1)

        Try
            _ThreadCount += Value
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log.Save(Log.Types.Error, ComponentID, TaskUID, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Decrement the internal thread count property by the amount in the value provided.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Value">The amount to decrement the thread count by.</param>
    Public Sub DecrementThreadCount(Optional Value As Integer = 1)

        Try
            If _ThreadCount > 0 Then
                _ThreadCount -= Value
            Else
                _ThreadCount = 0
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log.Save(Log.Types.Error, ComponentID, TaskUID, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private disposedValue As Boolean

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)

        If Not disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then

            End If

            _ComponentID = 0
            _TaskUID = Guid.Empty
            _ThreadCount = 0
        End If

        disposedValue = True

    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose

        Dispose(True)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's its (abbreviated) implementation...

```
Private Shared taskTrack As TaskTracker = Nothing

Public Shared Function Start() As ResultPackage

    Try
        TaskUID = Guid.NewGuid()
        taskTrack = New TaskTracker(ComponentID, TaskUID)

        'let any listeners know the task has started
        Comms.ComponentStatus(ComponentID, True)

        'mark the start time of the total task
        compStart = Now

        Log.Save(Log.Types.Trace, ComponentID, TaskUID, _ClassName & " Started", "Successful start of the " & _ClassName & " component.")

        For Each cli As ClientMaster In ClientMaster.GetList(True)
            'inner try/catch so that we can continue to process clients even if one errors
            Try
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf processClient, cli)

                Log.Save(Log.Types.Trace, ComponentID, TaskUID, "Client Thread Queued", "Thread queued for Client [" & cli.ClientName & "].")

                taskTrack.IncrementThreadCount()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Log.Save(Log.Types.Error, ComponentID, TaskUID, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
            End Try
        Next

        Do Until taskTrack.ThreadCount = 0  'or some timespan has been reached for a catchall
            Thread.Sleep(500)
        Loop

        Comms.ComponentStatus(ComponentID, False)

        'mark the end time of the total task
        compEnd = Now

        Log.Save(Log.Types.Trace, ComponentID, TaskUID, _ClassName, "Successful end of the " & _ClassName & " component.")
        Log.Save(Log.Types.Trace, ComponentID, TaskUID, _ClassName & " Task Time", _ClassName & " task took " & FriendlyTimeSpan(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, compStart, compEnd)) & " to complete.")

        Comms.ComponentMessage(ComponentID, "Task Duration: " & FriendlyTimeSpan(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, compStart, compEnd)))
    Catch ex As Exception
        resPack.Result = ResultPackage.Results.Fail
        resPack.Alerts.Add(New ResultPackage.Alert("Exception in Start()", ex))
        Log.Save(Log.Types.Error, ComponentID, TaskUID, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        Throw
    End Try

    Return resPack

End Function

Private Shared Sub processClient(Client As ClientMaster)

    'do work

    'decrease the thread counter since this task is complete
    taskTrack.DecrementThreadCount()

End Sub
```